# Updating values from one column to another

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table named 'product':

```
ID    NET_PRICE  SALE_PRICE
-------------------------
0001  NULL       1232
0002  NULL       2100
...
7873  NULL       1287
```

I would like to move all values from SALE_PRICE column to NET_PRICE, so the final result would be:

```
ID    NET_PRICE  SALE_PRICE
-------------------------
0001  1232       NULL
0002  2100       NULL
...
7873  1287       NULL
```

Which would be the way to do it in Sqlite3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a normal [UPDATE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) will work:

```
UPDATE product
SET NET_PRICE = SALE_PRICE,
    SALE_PRICE = NULL;
```